# Spark YARN client job from host with hostname unknown to cluster?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have number of private hosts visible from YARN cluster by IP but not by host name. When they try to submit any Spark job in YARN client mode, there is try to connect driver host from cluster. As by defeult `spark.driver.host` is configured to local hostname, this fails.

So is there any nice option to handle this? Something like automatically set ``spark.driver.host` to client IP interface address which is used for connection to cluster?

- Correct DNS resolution is not option. Not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html it seems like it can take in an IP as well. So you dont have to set a hostname necessarily.

Ideally the value for that property must be the internal address for the cluster nodes.